# C++ Hash Table and Linked List Issues

Tags: c++, insert, hashmap

So I'm trying to work on a project for my C++ class where I read a .txt file that has 53 lines of cities, states, and superfluous information afterwards.

(example: Port Jervis,NY,New York,36071,Orange,36071,41.3782,-74.6909,16410.0,1317)

After reading the file, I separate out the city name (example: Port Jervis) and state code (example: NY) and uses the value of the two letters in the state code as the key for a hash table of 13 elements. So N=13 + Y=24 = key of 37, and since the hash has 13 elements it's 37 % 13 = hash-key of 11.

So far so good and I'm able to get all that done correctly, however when it comes to displaying the results is where I'm running into an issue as each element of the hash-table is missing one link in the linked list. So it only displays 40 outputs of the 53, with 1 missing per element and I'm really not sure why.

So I e-mailed my professor my code and he said that my insert method is not correct which he believes is causing this error. My current insert method looks like

```
void insert(int key, string city, string state)//insert value
{ 
  int hash = KeyModFunction(key); //function that's %13 for hash-key
  Node* tmpInsert = new Node(key, city, state); //create node to work with


  if(table[hash]==NULL)//checks if table is empty
  {
    table[hash] = tmpInsert; //if empty, make new node with key/city/state values
  }
  else//if not empty
  {
    Node *runner = table[hash]; //made node to run through the list
    while(runner->next != NULL)//make it to the end
    {
      runner=runner->next; // go go go
    }
    runner->next = tmpInsert; //and point the end at the new node to be inserted
  }
} //end insert
```

And my professor suggested it should look something more like

```
if(table[hash]->next == NULL)
{

table[hash]->next = tmpInsert;
table[hash]->myCity = city;
table[hash]->myState = state;

}
else
{
// You can figure out the else code based on the above
```

However, whenever I put that into my code, it no longer compiles and says there is a segment fault. But when I run it through a debugger it says "[Inferior 1 (process 5453) exited normally]" which I'm not going to lie, I'm not sure what the means and have been unable to find a concrete answer online for. But I'm assuming the exited normally is a good thing, however, nothing is displayed.

I've been beating my head against this all week trying to figure out a solution and it's finally come to the point where I know I'm just getting too in my own head about it, so I've come here hoping to find some guidance, advice, or at the very least someone to point me in the right direction. If more of my code is needed on here, let me know, I just didn't want to dump my whole project on here cause I legitimately want to figure it out instead of having someone just do it for me, but yeah, I'm stuck. Thanks in advance for any help!

****2:12PST - 5/17/2020 UPDATE****

So in all fairness the insert code was plucked and modified from other peoples code I've found online looking into how to do this, so that might be why it looks better than my professor (also I'm pretty sure he mention C++ isn't his most familiar language). And yes, we are supposed to implement the hash table ourselves.

So here is the full program:

```
class Node{
  public:
    int key;
    string myCity;
    string myState;
    Node *next;

    Node(int key, string myCity, string myState)//constructor
    {
      this->key = key;
      this->myCity = myCity;
      this->myState = myState;
      this->next = NULL;
    }
};//end Node



class Hash{
  private:
    int BUCKET; //number of over all values
    Node** table;

  public:
    //Constructor
    Hash(int V)
    { 
      this->BUCKET = V; //setting the BUCKET size to max number of enteries 
      table = new Node*[BUCKET]; //create table with size of BUCKET
      for(int i = 0; i < BUCKET; i++) //fill table with NULL values
      {
        table[i] = NULL;
      }
    } //end constructor

    //KeyModFunction
    int KeyModFunction(int x) //getting the hash key value
    { 
      return (x % BUCKET); 
    } //end KeyModFunction


    //Insert Function
    void insert(int key, string city, string state)//insert value
{ 
  int hash = KeyModFunction(key); //function that's %13 for hash-key
  Node* tmpInsert = new Node(key, city, state); //create node to work with


  if(table[hash]==NULL)//checks if table is empty
  {
    table[hash] = tmpInsert; //if empty, make new node with key/city/state values
  }
  else//if not empty
  {
    Node *runner = table[hash]; //made node to run through the list
    while(runner->next != NULL)//make it to the end
    {
      runner=runner->next; // go go go
    }
    runner->next = tmpInsert; //and point the end at the new node to be inserted
  }
} //end insert

    //Display function
    void displayHash()
    {
      for(int loop = 0; loop < BUCKET; loop++)
      {
        cout<<loop;
        if(table[loop]->next != NULL)
        {
          Node* tmp;
          tmp = table[loop]->next;
          do
          {
            cout<<" -->"<<tmp->myCity<<"/"<<tmp->myState;
            tmp = tmp->next;
          }while(tmp!=NULL);
        }
        cout<<endl;
      }
    }//end displayHash

}; //end Hash Class



int main() {

  cout << "CSP 31B - Read and Process Assignment\n\n";

  char myAlpha[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //the key array for all the letter values
  Hash myTbl(13); //create hashmap with BUCKET size of 13

  string fCity, fState, fExtra; //string variables to hold info
  int key = 0; //hash value of the state code (two letters added together)

  ifstream myfile("CityOut.txt");

  while ( getline(myfile, fCity, ',') && getline(myfile, fState, ','))
  {
    getline(myfile, fExtra);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(myAlpha)/sizeof(myAlpha[0]); i++)
    {
      if(fState.at(0) == myAlpha[i])
      {
        key += i;
      }
      else if(fState.at(1) == myAlpha[i])
      {
        key += i;
      }
    }
    int checkNum = 1;
    cout << "DEBUGGER: City name: "<<fCity <<"   State code: " << fState.at(0) << fState.at(1) <<"     key = "<<key<<endl; //temporary statement for debugging purposes

    myTbl.insert(key, fCity, fState);
    key = 0; //reset hash number to zero for next line of CityOut.txt
  }

  cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;

  myTbl.displayHash();

  return 0;
}//end main
```

Then the output should look something like:
[image]

but each table element should have 1 more output

Comment: What does your function that prints the results look like?

Comment: Do you have to implement the hash table yourself, or could you just use [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)? If you have to implement it yourself, you could probably learn a lot by just having a look at `std::unordered_map`'s interface, which satisfies pretty much what your professor suggests.

Comment: Frankly your code looks better than the professors (which makes no sense to me at all).

Comment: Also note that your `if`-`else` is redundant. The `while` loop will suffice to find the end of your (presumably) single-linked list. However, with the information you posted I don't think anybody will be able to find your bug.

Comment: I agree with Buddy, the bug could just as easily be in the printing code as the inserting code. Since you are using a debugger, what does that tell you about how the insert function is working? At what point do the extra elements go missing?

Comment: Alright, updated my post with the full source code and an example out the intended output (though still missing values). And the display code was also provided to us by my professor (since the whole Covid19 lock-down stuff, we fell behind where we were supposed to be at). And seeing as how there seems to be a consensus with preferring the original insert over his, I wouldn't be surprised if the why he implemented his display isn't fully compatible with what I have

Comment: oops, this was an older iteration of it, all that was changed is the insert method, which the most recent version that I'm using is posted above. But fixed for copy and paste purposes

Comment: `if(table[loop]->next != NULL) tmp = table[loop]->next;` This code in `displayHash` very deliberately skips the first node in each bucket, for reasons unclear. It doesn't display the contents of `*table[loop]`, the first node in each list.

Comment: Ahhh!!!! @IgorTandetnik Thank you so much!! Just a simple switch that to Node* tmp = table[loop], then totally got ride of the "if(table[loop]->next != NULL)" , and tada! works perfectly! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your print code skips the first element of your hash table.

This code:

```
        cout<<loop;
        if(table[loop]->next != NULL)
        {
          Node* tmp;
          tmp = table[loop]->next;
          do
          {
            cout<<" -->"<<tmp->myCity<<"/"<<tmp->myState;
            tmp = tmp->next;
          }while(tmp!=NULL);
        }
```

Should be :

```
        cout<<loop;
        if(table[loop] != NULL)
        {
          Node* tmp;
          tmp = table[loop];
          do
          {
            cout<<" -->"<<tmp->myCity<<"/"<<tmp->myState;
            tmp = tmp->next;
          }while(tmp!=NULL);
        }
```